# Restore default Webhook in Telegram BOT

Tags: telegram-bot

How i can restore the default telegram webhook to a BOT. I set it to empity and now my BOT don't answer to commands.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `/deletewebhook` method but then it´ll send your requests nowhere. Maybe you could try to move your bot from webhook to the `/getupdates` function...

To compare these models and for more information about the methods look at [this part of the documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates)